# How to undo my branch changes after merging in github?

Tags: git

We are 2 developer team and my lead developer works directly on master branch. I recently joined and I created a feature branch at commit 31752197.

I made few commits(4f18c15, d0e05348, 6bfce681) on my feature branch.
In the meantime, my lead commited 395f0657.
At this point, I merged my feature branch to master. But after merging, I noticed some errors on master branch. Now, how to undo my merge so that on master only my lead developer changes are present.

After undoing, expected master branch commit history should look like
92ecc7a9, ac3a03db,31752197, 395f0657.

[image]

Comment: See here how to: [Reverting a pull request](https://help.github.com/en/articles/reverting-a-pull-request). Also you could just fix and submit a new change (the fix).

Comment: Do you have a merge commit or a fast forward? If you have a merge commit, can't you just revert that?